# how to solve error setting webhook in telegram

Tags: c#, bots, telegram

I have a bot in Telegram and tried to run it in Plesk Host (have SSL at port 443)

When I run the robot page in Visual Studio, the bot runs well.
After I publish/upload project to my plesk host and i open the robot page, the bot also runs well

But after setting a webhook, the bot doesn't run.
After 1.6 min in webhookInfo I get the following:

```
{
   "ok":true,
   "result":{
      "url":"https://MYDOMAIN:443/Robot.aspx",
      "has_custom_certificate":false,
      "pending_update_count":1,
      "last_error_date":1598521211,
      "last_error_message":"Read timeout expired",
      "max_connections":40
   }
}
```

My Source Code :

```
public class Robot : Page
{
    private const string Token = "1257942485:AAFMeYMX187lEeN8XHCEtSyCVoXXXX";
    private HttpToSocks5Proxy proxy = new HttpToSocks5Proxy(
        socks5Hostname: "so5tel.XXXX.org",
        socks5Port: 6500,
        username: "XXXX",
        password: "XXXX"
    );
    private static ITelegramBotClient _botClient;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        proxy.ResolveHostnamesLocally = true;
        RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(RunBot));
        ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();
    }
    private async Task RunBot()
    {
        _botClient = new TelegramBotClient(Token, proxy);
        _botClient.OnMessage += Bot_OnMsgAsync;
        _botClient.OnReceiveError += _botClient_OnReceiveError;
        _botClient.StartReceiving();
    }
    async void Bot_OnMsgAsync(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        await _botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, e.Message.Text).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    private void _botClient_OnReceiveError(object sender, ReceiveErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter we = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("file.txt"), true))
        {
            we.WriteLine(e.ApiRequestException.Message + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

in file.txt i get the following:

```
Conflict: can't use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first
```

How can i solve it?